# MVC 3: Uncertain of RegisterGlobalFilters Behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, windows-authentication

I've setup the **ReisterGlobalFilters** method like this in my Global.asax:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());

    var testUsers = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["testUsers"];

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testUsers))
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute{ Users = testUsers });
    }
}
```

Which reads that value from the Web.Config like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="testUsers" value="DOMAIN\MyDomainAccount, DOMAIN\SomeoneElse"
</appSettings>
```

Production config transform does this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="testUsers"
         xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

Certain actions are decorated like this:

```
[Authorize(Users = "DOMAIN\Special Users Group")]
public ActionResult SomeAction(){ ... }
```

Problem is, in Debug mode I still can't access those restricted Controller actions using my domain account. I've attached the debugger to the **RegisterGlobalFilters** method, and the value of "testUsers" is assigned the correct value from the web.config.

What's going on here?

Comment: Does you domain account belong to the `DOMAIN\Special Users Group` group?

Comment: No, but I'm under the impression adding my domain account via the Global Action Filters will give me access. Am I mistaken?

Comment: yes, you are mistaken. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global attribute that you have defined in your web.config is OK. In debug you are authenticated. But the other Authorize attribute that you put on your controller action doesn't allow you because your account doesn't belong to the `DOMAIN\Special Users Group` group and it simply denies the authorization. You could have multiple authorization attributes on a given action but as long as one deines authorization it's game over.

Comment: Ok, dang. You see what I'm trying to accomplish here... any suggestions on how to get something like this working?

Comment: @ErOx, sure, see this hardcoded `Users = "DOMAIN\Special Users Group"` in your authorize attribute? That's what's busting you and since those values must be constant and know at compile time what you could do is write your custom authorize attribute deriving from AuthorizeAttribute and in which you will fetch this value from `web.config`. So you will then simply decorate your controller action with `[MySpecialUsersAuthorize]` attribute.